# Error when Unit Testing async Task<IHttpActionResult>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following method in one of my controllers:-

```
//GET: api/Books/5
[ResponseType(typeof(BookDetailDTO))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBook(int id)
{
    var includeProperties = "Author,Genre";
    var item = _bookRepository.GetBookById(id, includeProperties);
    //var item = await Task.Run(() => _bookRepository.GetBookById(id, includeProperties));
}
```

and I am trying to create a unit test against it :-

```
[Test]
public async Task GetBook_Should_Get_A_Single_Book_By_Its_ID()
{
    // Arrange
    _booksRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetBooks("Author")).Returns(books.AsQueryable());

    // Act
    var result = await objController.GetBook(1) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Book>;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(books[1].Title, result.Content.Title);
}
```

The problem is that on the following line:-

```
var item = _bookRepository.GetBookById(id, includeProperties);
```

the `item` is always null since the `_bookRepository` which is now mocked is not being hit.  However when running the actual application, it works fine and I get the book by its `ID`.

How can I tweak the test/code and make it run successfully?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example so that we can see the problem locally.

Comment: Hi Stephen, how exactly?  I mean that is all the code I have not working

Comment: Reduce the code bit by bit until it's something you can copy into a new VS project and run. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stephen I shortened a bit the code, and also noticed that the problem is actually the mock repository and not the await

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at it you're not testing the right thing.

What you are testing is your db layer so you can do away with all the async stuff.

Unit testing is about going down to a very granular level and testing that one little simple thing, not an api async call which hits a database. That's an integration test not a unit test.

So write your test method against your db layer and leave it at that. Your api will return the right thing, IF the db layer functions correctly.

Update

Here's what I would do.

Write a unit test for your database layer. Keep your current mocking code, set up your mock book object and check you get it when you fire the GetBookByID method. That's at book repo level so you're testing you're getting the right. It could be a BookRepoTest class where this test happens.

Now, I would add an extra layer in between your repo and your controller. A generic way to get data, Imagine a layer which looks like this :

```
public DataAccess class
{
    IRepo _repo;
    public DataAccess( IRepo repo){
         _repo = repo;
    }

    public GetRepo(){
        return _repo;
    }
}
```

of course there will be a bit more code but the idea is to inject the dependency. Now you can mock this dependency without touching your actual repo at all. Then you go ahead and check your controller, what happens when the input model is wrong, when the id doesn't exist etc.

Now you've separated the code and made it easier to test. I always do the same when building my projects. The moment you see stuff like that UnitOfWork in your controller, it's a smell already that you don't have enough Separation of concerns.
From your current code it's not even clear if that mocked repo is actually used once the UnitOfWork method is called.

You could even add the repo dependency (based on the interface ) to the constructor of the controller itself. Then you can inject that way as well. Whichever method is easier and applicable to you.

Comment: Hi Andrei, didn't quite understand you.  I need to test that the Repo and the Controller are actually working and returning the correct data no? And to test that I need to mock my repo

Comment: What I am saying is that you're doing too much in that test. What are you testing? Are you testing that the controller works or that the repo works? If you're testing both then that's too much for a unit test. Break it down a little and test one thing at a time.

Comment: Andrei, can you give me a small example on how to achieve that?  My idea was to pass a fake book I created in my test project, and verify that once it passes through the controller and repository, I get the result I am after

Comment: I added a few more ideas, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Andrei so instead of the UnitOfWork, the repository shoud be injected in the controller right?

Comment: I would inject it yes. This gives you the flexibility to change your db layer should you need that, but the most important gain is that you abstract it away and can now replace it with a mock easily.

Comment: So you are against the use of UnitOfWork becuase of decoupling?

Comment: And injecting the repo however will still not solve my await problem would it not?